# iOS - Animate movement of an image without effects

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview

I would like to animate the movement of an image without effects. To animate it normally, I could use:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.5f animations:^{
    CGRect currentFrame=self.image.frame;
    currentFrame.origin.x-=10;

    [self.image setFrame:currentFrame];

}];
```

Yet, I found that if this method is used, the image gradually speeds up, goes a little faster, then gradually comes to a stop.

Is there any way to animate the movement of a UIImageView, keeping the view at the same speed the entire time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your animation speeds up and slows down because it uses the "natural" `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut` curve. Use `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear` option to use constant speed motion:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.5f
    delay:0
    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
    animations:^{
        CGRect currentFrame=self.image.frame;
        currentFrame.origin.x-=10;
        [self.image setFrame:currentFrame];
    } 
    completion:^(BOOL finished){
    }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:0 animations:^{

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

}];
```

Comment: Try to avoid code-only answers... Even though this is correct, someone looking at it would have no clue what the code does.